C++ - Get real typename of the derived class from base class
For example, I can do something like this using CRTP:
template<typename Self>
struct Sharable {
    int count = 0;

    template<typename... Args>
    static Self *create(Args &&...args) {
        Self *res = new Self(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        res->count = 1;
        return res;
    }

    Self *dup() {
        ++count;
        return static_cast<Self *>(this);
    }

    void drop() {
        if (--count == 0) {
            delete static_cast<Self *>(this);
        }
    }
};

struct Object : Sharable<Object> {
    int val1;
    Object(int v1) : val1(v1) {}
};

int main() {
    Object *ptr = Object::create(1);
}

However, the problem is that, using this pattern, if there is a class that continues to inherit from the Object class, then on the one hand, there will be two duplicate count members in the subclass, and on the other hand, there will be multiple copies of methods such as create, dup, and drop, resulting in ambiguous method calls.
struct Child : Object, Sharable<Child> {
    int val2;
    Child(int v1, int v2) : Object(v1), val2(v2) {}
};

int main() {
    Child *ptr = Child::create(1, 2);
    // error: member 'create' found in multiple base classes of different types
}

I've learned that the deduce this feature in C++23 can do something related:
struct SharedMemory {
    std::size_t count = 0;

    template<typename Self>
    Self *dup() {
        ++count;
        return static_cast<Self *>(this);
    }

    template<typename Self>
    void drop() {
        if (--count == 0) {
            delete static_cast<Self *>(this);
        }
    }
};

However, this only seems to work for those non-static methods (dup and drop), is it possible to do the same for static methods? (It would be better if this could be done without C++23 features)
Note: Here, I want create to be a member method of the Shared class, rather than implementing it as a template function outside the class, because I need the memory of some other classes to be managed in other ways (for example, there may be some other classes inherits from another base class Global instead of Sharable, whose create, dup, drop methods operate on a global memory)

are you looking for virtual inheritance?

The problem is that deleting a pointer may only be done on the base class if the object is virtual. This means that a reference counter must either know the type (which is hard to design if you make multiple levels of derived classes), or be a virtual class with a virtual destructor. Be careful of multiple inheritance, you cannot (indirectly) inherit Sharable more than once, as this will call delete multiple times via destructors if you use RAII. (or give the multiple drop() versions as you noticed if you dont use RAII)

if you want to avoid c++23 you should rather tag c++20

@Aedoro -- I think that your comment is correct, but be careful with the word "virtual". An object cannot be virtual, and a class cannot be virtual. Member functions and destructors can be virtual, and a class can use virtual inheritance (so the base is a virtual base).

Note that not using CRTP, but regular template is the way used by std::shared_ptr

Unrelated note: unless you are sure that you will always use the pattern in a single thread, you should definitely have a std::atomic<int>for count.

With virtual inheritance and providing base to CRTP, you might do:
struct RefCounter
{
    virtual ~RefCounter() = default;
    int count = 1;
};

template<typename Self, typename... Bases>
struct Sharable : protected virtual RefCounter, public Bases...
{

    Sharable(Bases... bases) : Bases(bases)... {}

    template<typename... Args>
    static Self *create(Args &&...args) {
        return new Self(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    Self *dup() {
        ++count;
        return static_cast<Self *>(this);
    }

    void drop() {
        if (--count == 0) {
            delete static_cast<Self *>(this);
        }
    }
};

struct Object : Sharable<Object> {
    int val1;
    Object(int v1) : val1(v1) {}
};

struct Child : Sharable<Child, Object> {
    int val2;
    Child(int v1, int v2) : Sharable(v1), val2(v2) {}
};

Demo
